# XML parsing and transforming (XSLT or otherwise)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I have several xml files that are formated this way:

```
<ROOT>
  <OBJECT>
    <identity>
        <id>123</id>
    </identity>     
    <child2 attr = "aa">32</child2>
    <child3>
        <childOfChild3 att1="aaa" att2="bbb" att3="CCC">LN</childOfChild3>
    </child3>
    <child4>
        <child5>
            <child6>3ddf</child6>
            <child7>
                <childOfChild7 att31="RR">1231</childOfChild7>
            </child7>
        </child5>
    </child4>
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <identity>
        <id>124</id>
    </identity>     
    <child2 attr = "bb">212</child2>
    <child3>
        <childOfChild3 att1="ee" att2="ccc" att3="EREA">OP</childOfChild3>
    </child3>
    <child4>
        <child5>
            <child6>213r</child6>
            <child7>
                <childOfChild7 att31="EE">1233</childOfChild7>
            </child7>
        </child5>
    </child4>
  </OBJECT>
</ROOT>
```

How can i format it this way?:

```
<ROOT>
    <OBJECT>    
        <id>123</id>
        <child2>32</child2> 
        <attr>aa</attr>
        <child3></child3>
        <childOfChild3>LN</childOfChild3>
        <att1>aaa</att1>
        <att2>bbb</att2>
        <att3>CCC</att3>
        <child4></child4>
        <child5></child5>
        <child6>3ddf</child6>
        <child7></child7>
        <childOfChild7>1231</childOfChild7>
        <att31>RR</att31>
    </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT>    
        <id>124</id>
        <child2>212</child2>    
        <attr>bb</attr>
        <child3></child3>
        <childOfChild3>LN</childOfChild3>
        <att1>ee</att1>
        <att2>ccc</att2>
        <att3>EREA</att3>
        <child4></child4>
        <child5></child5>
        <child6>213r</child6>
        <child7></child7>
        <childOfChild7>1233</childOfChild7>
        <att31>EE</att31>
    </OBJECT>   
</ROOT>
```

I know some C# so maybe a parser there? or some generic xslt? 
The xml files are some data received from a client, so i can't control the way they are sending it to me.

L.E. Basically when i am trying to test this data in excel (for example i want to make sure that the attribute of childOfChild7 corresponds to the correct identity id) i am getting a lot of blank spaces. If i am importing in access to get only the data i want out, i have to do a thousands subqueries to get them all in a nice table. Basically i just want to see for one Object all its data (one object - One row) and then just delete/hide the columns i don't need.

Comment: Why do you want to reformat the original xml? Your new format looks extremely denormalized...

Comment: In addition to the example output, could you describe the desired transformation using words, so that we have less work (and mistakes) inferring the transformation rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="OBJECT//*[not(self::identity) and text()]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::text())]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="OBJECT//*[not(self::identity) and (not(text()))]">
  <xsl:copy/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="identity">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ROOT>
    <OBJECT>
        <identity>
            <id>123</id>
        </identity>
        <child2 attr = "aa">32</child2>
        <child3>
            <childOfChild3 att1="aaa" att2="bbb" att3="CCC">LN</childOfChild3>
        </child3>
        <child4>
            <child5>
                <child6>3ddf</child6>
                <child7>
                    <childOfChild7 att31="RR">1231</childOfChild7>
                </child7>
            </child5>
        </child4>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT>
        <identity>
            <id>124</id>
        </identity>
        <child2 attr = "bb">212</child2>
        <child3>
            <childOfChild3 att1="ee" att2="ccc" att3="EREA">OP</childOfChild3>
        </child3>
        <child4>
            <child5>
                <child6>213r</child6>
                <child7>
                    <childOfChild7 att31="EE">1233</childOfChild7>
                </child7>
            </child5>
        </child4>
    </OBJECT>
</ROOT>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<ROOT>
   <OBJECT>
      <id>123</id>
      <child2>32</child2>
      <attr>aa</attr>
      <child3/>
      <childOfChild3>LN</childOfChild3>
      <att1>aaa</att1>
      <att2>bbb</att2>
      <att3>CCC</att3>
      <child4/>
      <child5/>
      <child6>3ddf</child6>
      <child7/>
      <childOfChild7>1231</childOfChild7>
      <att31>RR</att31>
   </OBJECT>
   <OBJECT>
      <id>124</id>
      <child2>212</child2>
      <attr>bb</attr>
      <child3/>
      <childOfChild3>OP</childOfChild3>
      <att1>ee</att1>
      <att2>ccc</att2>
      <att3>EREA</att3>
      <child4/>
      <child5/>
      <child6>213r</child6>
      <child7/>
      <childOfChild7>1233</childOfChild7>
      <att31>EE</att31>
   </OBJECT>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do it by flattening it out.  You take all the descendants of the OBJECTS and turn them into elements.  You should really try this for yourself instead of just accepting my code, but it works so you can test it vs what you come up with.

```
XElement root1 = XElement.Load(file1);
XElement root = new XElement("ROOT",
    root1.Elements()
        .Select(o => new XElement(o.Name, o
            .Descendants()
            .Select(x =>
            {
                List<XElement> list = new List<XElement>();
                list.Add(new XElement(x.Name, x.HasElements ? "" : x.Value));
                if (x.HasAttributes)
                    list.AddRange(x.Attributes()
                        .Select(a => new XElement(a.Name, a.Value))
                        );
                return list;
            })
            ))
            .ToArray());
```

PS. You forgot `<identity></identity>` in your result set.

Answer (score 1):

Just use XmlSerializer to deserialize it into a class, here is an [msdn post on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), basically you build a class that matches your xml structure and then let the XmlSerializer class do the conversion, you shouldn't need to create your own parser

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with C# but I am hoping this will atleast get you started. I had to do something similar, where I would get a XML file and parse the information into a database.

I used a Java lib ~ [StAX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP3.html). It will allow you read the XML file and parse the information into another XML file quite easily using the parent - child system. I hope this helped a little.